# Call a function in background from popup

Tags: function, background, popup, google-chrome-extension, call

Is there a way to call a function in the background script from the popup? I can't explain it much further than that question. It's not an error I'm having with what I'm trying to do but rather something I completely don't know how to do. I want to make it possible to click a button in the popup page that'll call a function defined in the background page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate between popup.js and background.js in chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546778/how-to-communicate-between-popup-js-and-background-js-in-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 26):

Try this

```
 var bgPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
 var dat =  bgPage.paste(); // Here paste() is a function that returns value.
```

Comment: I knew I _could_ do this, just needed to find an example. Thanks.

Comment: Worked, but I had to define my function as `window.myFun = ...` instead of just `function myFun ...`

Answer (score 16):

It is indeed possible, using [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

popup.js

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "startFunc" });
});
```

background.js

```
var func = function(){
    alert("Success!");
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        if(request.msg == "startFunc") func();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just call background.js functions in popup.js. You don't need to do anything extra. At least that is the case for me.

Edit: you probably need to add

`"background": {
      "scripts": "background.js"
}`

in your manifest.json file.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `chrome.extension.sendMessage`. 
But that is getting deprecated. 
Use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` instead.