# Chrome extension persistent popup best practices

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've understood from the docs that closing chrome extension popups when losing focus has been a design choice.

I'm working on an extension where the user chooses to save elements from a webpage. As he interacts with the main webpage I would like the popup to get updated but that's obviously not possible.

What's the proper way of handling this situation? (this is my first chrome extension)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) detect the "save" action. Let's suppose it's a specific DOM element you know for sure it's going to be in the specific main, or that you create by yourself.

**content.js**

```
//content script
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    // Grab the UI frmo the mainpage you want to append the save functionality
    var someElementsYouWantToAppendASaveButtonTo = document.getElementsByTagName("...");

    var len = someElementsYouWantToAppendASaveButtonTo.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        // Create a UI save button to provide a functionality
        var theSaveButton = document.createElement("button");
        theSaveButton.value = "Save to Chrome Extension";

        // Send data to extension when clicked
        theSaveButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var dataToSentToExtension = {...} // Retrieve from the clicked element, or whatever you want to save
            chrome.extension.sendMessage(dataToSentToExtension, function(response) {
                if(response.success) console.log("Saved successfully");
                else console.log("There was an error while saving")
            });
        }, false); 

        someElementsYouWantToAppendASaveButtonTo[i].appendChild(theSaveButton)
    }
}
}
```

Then, on the background, you detect the response and set up the popup as you wish.

**background.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.dataToSave) {
        chrome.storage.local.set(dataToSave, function() {...});

        // You can then set upn the proper popup for the next click or even switch to it
        switch(request.popupToDisplay) {
            case "awesomeDisplay":
            chrome.browserAction.setPopup({...})
            break;
        }


        var responseFromExtension = {success: true}
    } else {
        var responseFromExtension = {error: true}
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to open the popup programmatically?

Comment: tl;dr No. Full long sentence answer so the commenting system can allow me to put a comment: No.

Comment: You could add an iframe to the page that mimics the popup.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking to modify\update your `popup.html` page in accord to changes in a web page. If so, use content scripts and establish [connection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-connect) for single message [communication](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-sendMessage) with `background page`(Since focus is lost every time) and update `popup.html` indirectly.

### References:

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)
- [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546778/how-to-communicate-between-popup-js-and-background-js-in-chrome-extension/13549245#13549245) for communication between `popup` and `background page` apart from these,
there are bunch of questions on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-chrome-extension%5D%20message%20passing) topics, they will get you started..

Comment: Is there a way to open the popup programmatically?

Comment: @MB.:There is **no** mechanism to open `popup` programmatically till date