# Sending message from popup.js in Chrome extension to background.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What is the proper way to send a message (and get a response) to background.js from popup.js in a Chrome extension? Every method I try ends up with an error that:

"Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

I would prefer to use chrome.extension.sendMessage() over chrome.extension.connect() with port.postMessage(), but neither method seems to have worked.

What I am trying to do is wire a button in the popup.html to call into some javascript in popup.js which calls back to background.js in an effort to get info about the currentTab() that was topMost (ie:to get the current URL string to show in the popup.html)

Right now in **popup.js** (wired to the action of the button) I have:

```
function getURL()
{
   chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "GetURL"}, 
          function(response) { tabURL = response.navURL });

   $("#tabURL").text(tabURL);
}
```

In **background.js** I have:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener( function(request,sender,sendResponse)
{
    if( request.greeting == "GetURL" )
    {
        var tabURL = "Not set yet";
        chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){
            tabURL = tab.url;
        });

        sendResponse( {navURL:tabURL} );
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: see this answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546778/how-to-communicate-between-popup-js-and-background-js-in-chrome-extension/47545616#47545616

Answer (score 39):

Just to clarify, we talking about communication between popup page from browserAction and background script?

Anyway you have quite a few errors in your code.

**First** your totally ignore the fact that all callbacks in chrome api are **asynchronous**.

In background page

```
    var tabURL = "Not set yet";
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
        tabURL = tab.url;
    }); //this will be invoked somewhere in the future

    sendResponse({ navURL: tabURL }); 
    //navUrl will be always Not set yet because callback of getCurrent hasn't been called yet
```

Same in popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ greeting: "GetURL" }, 
          function(response) { tabURL = response.navURL });//callback will be invoked somewhere in the future

$("#tabURL").text(tabURL)//tabURL will display something totally different from what you have been expected
```

**Second** error is that `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` doesn't give you the current tab selected by user in main window. The [docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-getCurrent) says:

> Gets the tab that this script call is being made from. May be
> undefined if called from a non-tab context (for example: a background
> page or popup view).

So you will get undefined for all of your requests, because you call it in background page. What you need to do is to use method [chrome.tabs.query](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)  to obtain currently active tabs.

So after fixing all problems new code should look something like this:

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if(request.greeting === "GetURL")
    {
        var tabURL = "Not set yet";
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function(tabs) {
            if(tabs.length === 0) {
                sendResponse({});
                return;
            }
            tabURL = tabs[0].url;
            sendResponse({ navURL: tabURL });
        });        
    }
});
```

popup.js

```
function getURL() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "GetURL"},
        function (response) {
            tabURL = response.navURL;
            $("#tabURL").text(tabURL);
        });
}
```

Comment: Just to note, it looks like the Chrome extension API has deprecated chrome.extension.sendMessage and replaced it with chrome.runtime.sendMessage: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging