# Why can't I use jQuery after it's dynamically injected from a chrome extension's content-script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When run as a script in the usual way on a page, this code prints the version of jQuery after it is dynamically injected into a page. But in my chrome-extension, when I try to print jQuery's version after I dynamically inject it, the output is `undefined`.

```
// create iframe
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");

// when frame loads
frame.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // create script to dynamically inject into DOM
  var script = frame.contentWindow.document.createElement("script");
  // when script loads print jquery version
  script.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log(frame.contentWindow.$.fn.jquery); // output -> 2.2.1
  });
  frame.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(script);
  script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js";
});

document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

#### So this is my problem:

I have to dynamically inject some code (I'm using jQuery as an example) into an iframe because I need it to have the correct context of the `iframe.contentWindow` as the window.

The problem is that whenever I try to use the global that is created with the a script such as **someModule.js** using `frame.contentWindow.someModule` (in this case it's `frame.contentWindow.$` since I injected the  jQuery source code) it is undefined. I think this is something to do with it being a chrome extension (like the chrome extension javascript is isolated from the other code)

### My question:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I bypass (or any solution to this) it?
   2.1. How can I dynamically add JavaScript (a file, or some code) so that it's in the context of an iFrame (and not the parent window). I must do it during run-time as it's a chrome extension with a content-script.

Or can I possibly run the chrome extension content-script directly in the iframe?

Fiddle with the code above:
https://jsfiddle.net/wj83oytd/5/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546778/how-to-communicate-between-popup-js-and-background-js-in-chrome-extension

Comment: Had to step away, but you can use `postMessage` to communicate. I believe for security concerns, you can't directly access the global state of the other iframe (although it'd be a pain to implement to so maybe that's part of it too).

Comment: @Cymen I'm not sure how that would work as I'm not using any background script for the chrome extension, all I have is the content-script

Comment: You can use `postMessage` to talk between other things too like iframes -- ie http://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html

Comment: @Cymen I see what you mean. Thing is, I didn't create the iframe or any part of the page that I'm running the content script on.

Comment: Ah! I misread/misunderstood, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Found the problem,

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated
> world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into,
> but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.
> It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript
> executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse:
> JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any
> variables defined by content scripts.
>
> ### https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment

### Solution,

Dynamically inject the code you want to run as inline JavaScript code as well, instead of running it in the content-script

Code that doesn't work:

```
 // calling it in the content-script
 console.log(frame.contentWindow.$.fn.jquery); // undefined
```

Solution:

```
var script = frame.contentWindow.document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = "console.log(window.$.fn.jquery);"; // set script code
// adding it to the frame and running it in it's context
frame.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(rmptipScript); // injects the code
// prints 2.2.1
```