# How to update data in the eventpage.js script to show them in the popup.html file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the eventpage.js script where I would like to get a data form a service and store it to the LocalStorage. After this, I would like to pull a data to the popup.html page which shows after I click on an extension icon. But, I found the issue that the EventPage can "live" only when the popup.html page is opened. How to refresh a data in the EventPage  after some timeout? Do I need to use Alarms in my Google Chrome Extension? If possible, please show a sample.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate between popup.js and background.js in chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546778/how-to-communicate-between-popup-js-and-background-js-in-chrome-extension)