# getDisplayMedia() not allowed in extension popup.js?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I would like to get the audio feed of a firefox tab by calling `getDisplayMedia()` from an extension's popup.js but even when directly called from an html button's click event it returns:
`DOMException: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context.`

and if I catch it:
`NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context.`

Here is a minimal example where it should work: [Keep running the screen recording even after the web extension is not visible on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68922915/keep-running-the-screen-recording-even-after-the-web-extension-is-not-visible-on)
but I get the same error when I try to run the code.

I have tried calling `getDisplayMedia()` from a content script by sending a message with `sendMessage()` from the popup to the script but the call has to be made directly from a user interaction so it doesn't work. From my understanding the other condition that prompts this error is that the context of the call is not https but I don't know how this affects popup.html or popup.js. Thanks for helping

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could you set up a minimal example that should work but doesn't? That would help us try to figure out if the issue is in the code or somewhere else.

Comment: @Hamatti I fixed the formatting to the link I mentionned which contains such an example