# Call backround js method from popup js in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to call a method in background.js from popup.js . Example :

Background js:

```
function abc(){

}
```

Popup js :

```
abc(); //call from here
```

Answer (score 0):

In popup.js :

```
var BGPAGE = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
BGPAGE.abc();
```

Also messaging can be used as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443202/call-a-function-in-background-from-popup)