# Set a variable from variable array outta options.html into background.js in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I create a Chrome extension and want add an option page where a radio buttons sets a variable from variable array in `background.js`.

I have `background.js` with a code like

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var protocol = "https://";
var country = ["de","ch"];
var middle = ".sistrix.com/toolbox/__loadModule/domain/";
var d = currentDomain();
var end = ".html";

xhr.open("GET", protocol+country+middle+d+end, true);
```

Further i have a file `options.html`, containing this code

```
<select>
  <option value="de">Germany</option>
  <option value="ch">Swiss</option>
</select>
```

Now i want that selecting of an option in `options.html` () sets corresponding variable from an array `var country = ["de","ch"];` into `xhr.open("GET", protocol+country+middle+d+end, true);` as `country`.

**Scenario**:

- user clicks with the right mouse button on the extension icon
- options page is opened,
- user selects an option, i.e. `de - Germany`
- after this and until user sets another option, `background.js` uses corresponding variable `de` from variable array `var country = ["de","ch"];` in `xhr.open` as `country`.

**PS**: some answers about passing data from popup to background don't match my need. I want to have options explicitely under options - here https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1232/thumbs/7819701093_b.jpg, not in popup, which opens after clicking with the left mouse button on extension icon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a function in background from popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443202/call-a-function-in-background-from-popup)

Comment: @Titus Not really - i want to have the option select not in `popup.js`, buit explicitely in options. As far i know `popup` opens after clicking on the extension icon with the left mouse button - i want to have it there: https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1232/thumbs/7819701093_b.jpg

Comment: All solutions in all the answers to that question will work on both pop-ups and options pages.

Comment: @Titus does it mean, in Method C of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13549245/1992004 i could use instead of `popup.html` and `popup.js` `options.html` and `options.js`?

Comment: Yes, that is right.